# Spring Mongodb $filter nested object using CriteriaDefinition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I have the following classes

```
@Document("artists")
public class Artist {
    private String name;
    private List<Album> discography;
    // Getters and Setters
}

public class Album {
    private String title;
    private Instant releaseDate;
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

My goal is to write an Aggregate function using Spring data mongodb that will allow me to first find an `Artist` by `name`, then look through the associated `List<Album>` and filter its contents based on a date range provided. It should then return a `List<Album>` with all the instances of `Album` that fell within that date range.

The main problem I'm having is that an instance of `CriteriaDefinition` is provided, and I need to construct the Aggregation and $filter conditions using the contents of it.

```
// A CriteriaDefinition gets passed into this method
// which contains various criteria to search on

Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.match(criteriaDefinition), //This returns the correct Artist, but with all Album objects
    Aggregation.project()
        .and(filter("album.discography")
        .as("discography")
        .by( //how do use a CriteriaDefinition here? )
    .as("albums")
);

List<Album> albums = mongoTemplate
            .aggregate(agg, Artist.class, Album.class);
return albums;
```

Is it even possible to filter on `CriteriaDefinition`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unwind` operator with a match on subdocuments. For example i filtered artists with name "foobar" and returned its albums with a releaseDate greater than now. 
Please try :

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                match(where("name").is("foobar")),
                unwind("discography"),
                match(where("discography.releaseDate").gt(new Date())));

AggregationResults<Album> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Artist.class, Album.class);
List<Album> albums = results.getMappedResults();
```